# Is "stripling" commonly understood in US English?

Tags: american-english

"Stripling" is an alternative word for a youth. According to the Cambridge Dictionary:

> stripling noun [ C ] /ˈstrɪp.lɪŋ/
>   old-fashioned or humorous ​
>   a young man.

It is derived from the use of the word "strip" as a description for something slim or narrow.

I used the word in an essay for publication recently and was surprised when my well-educated US proofreader confessed himself ignorant of its meaning. It's a little archaic but I think most British speakers would be familiar with it.

Is it a word that's absent from US English?

Comment: I am American and know the word; and ngram reveals no great difference in its frequency between [American](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stripling&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3) and [British](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stripling&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3) English. (Both show considerable decline in frequency since C19 but a slight resurgence in C21.)

Comment: I'm British, and while I'm vaguely familiar with it I wouldn't say that it's commonly used at all.  As far as etymology goes I'd always assumed it was a botanical reference, perhaps meaning something like "sapling".  This is actually not the case at all.

Comment: I'm American and in my 60s.  I'm modestly familiar with the word, though I'd probably never use it myself unless I was attempting to reproduce old-timey speech.  I would guess that younger folks are less familiar with it, since I mainly got it from old books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Brian Donovan notes in a comment, no appreciable difference in the prevalence of *stripling* can be found in British vs. American books according to the [Google Books Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stripling%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cstripling%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1850&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3):

[image: Google NGram comparing prevalence of 'stripling' in UK and US corpora]

A search of [COCA and COHA](https://www.english-corpora.org/) suggests that by the 1990s, *stripling* was found mainly in literature, but this is also true when searching the BNC. Of the six entries in the latter for the 1980s through 1993, four are from fiction, and two are ironic uses in newspapers.

For what it's worth, I'm American and know the word, but cannot recall ever using it myself; I don't perceive it as British, as say *chap* or *lad*, but it does sound affected, as say *whippersnapper* or *youngster*. That seems to align with Cambridge's usage note that *stripling* is *old-fashioned or humorous*.